# SSIS Missing Method Exception with CRM

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm-2011, sql-agent-job

I have an SSIS package that I am attempting to set up as a SQL Server Agent Job. This package takes XML files and inserts/ updates records in Dynamics CRM 2011. In my development environment, the execution works correctly. However, when deployed to the server (which is the same domain as the database concerned), when executing a System.MissingMethodException is thrown.

[image: Exception in Package Execution]

The machine definitely has the DynamicsCRM2011.dll in the GAC - this machine has both the database and teh instance of CRM2011 running on it. On my test machine, I was connecting to this server (which is on a different domain) without incident. I get the same issue for all users whether integrated security is used or not.

The files are correctly read, this error is happening when declaring the CRM service and assigning a new Helper from the service (CRM2011.Proxy.Helper).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure u added the dll in GAC? You can copy the dll in the same folder as the SSIS Package.

Comment: Yes, definitely registered in the GAC. I have successfully deployed to a different machine too, but one particular machine is always failing.